# "All" vs. "All the"

Tags: articles, definite-article

I wrote

> Alternatively, we can use any constant element repeating in all items, such as ``Add to Cart".

Here by **items** I mean all items on the page or all items of a list, but still I don't know if I should use "all the items" or "all items". I remember once I used "all the elements" to mean "all the elements on the page" but I saw "all elements" in the answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is the same as with any other use of the... 'All' makes no difference

If you are talking about a specific group, you would use the:

> Pass me all the apples in the bowl

If you are talking about apples as a 'thing' but not as individual apples, you would not use the:

> All apples are delicious

To translate this to your case, if you are talking about the elements on one page you would use the:

> Some of the elements on the page are left aligned, the rest are justified. It looks strange.

If you are talking about elements in general you would not:

> All elements need both a class and ID, otherwise the JavaScript breaks

Note that in the latter case of both examples we are talking about apples/elements as a 'thing' or concept, whereas in the former we are talking about individual objects.

Comment: The partitive “of the” portion in “X of the” expressions like *few/some/many/most/several/all of the* is best avoided in careful writing: your writing will be stronger without it. Your example with *some* at its start should therefore arguably be: “Some page elements are left-aligned; the rest are justified. It looks strange.”

Comment: While I agree, I felt it would confuse the issue in this case: I decided to just answer the question as-is

Comment: @JonStory What about this one:  'All products I use are from company x' Do I need to say 'the' even if the context implies what kind of products I mean ( in this case cosmetic products)? My wife corrected me and said it should be 'all the products'. It sounds fine both ways.

Comment: @Chris That would be covered in the answer.  You're no longer talking about the individual products ("the products") and are instead talking about "products" as a concept/group. It would be akin to saying "All apples are delicious". It works because you're including the qualifier "I use", which limits your statement to a small subset of all products. "All products are from this company", for example, wouldn't fit this rule.

Comment: @JonStory  I knew there was something! Thank you for clearing it up for me!

Comment: @Chris No problem, please blow a raspberry at your wife for me when you deliver your own "I told you so" :p